# Python - performance issue -- filter pandas dataframe versus filter list of dics vs numpy recs

Tags: python, performance, pandas

I am new to Python and also am more than new with pandas.

I would like to use it but comparing pandas filtering of two cols with a list of dictionaries (80 rows both), it seems to have a huge performance difference. my big question is why pandas takes so long to run.

**pandas dataFrame**

```
timeit a = dfEnts[(dfEnts["col"]=="ro") & (dfEnts["sty"]=="hz")]
```

1000 loops, best of 3: **239 us** per loop

**vs simple list of dics**

```
timeit b = [ix for ix,ent in enumerate(ents) if (ent['col']=="ro") & (ent["sty"]=="hz")]
```

100000 loops, best of 3: **11.4 us** per loop

**vs numpy structured/record array**

```
timeit a = entsRec[(entsRec["col"]=="ro") & (entsRec["sty"]=="hz")]
```

100000 loops, best of 3: **18.2 us** per loop

Is there any other good way to use pandas but having similar response time?

---

scripts goes like this..

```
ents = []

for idx in xrange(0,80)

    dic = {'n':f, 'p':props,'li':li,'col':col,'sty':sty,'nu':nu,'ge':ge,'rr':rr,'ssty':ssty} 
    ents.append(dic)

# DataFrame
dfEnts = pd.DataFrame(ents)

# np rec array
entsTuples = [(ent[ 'n'],ent['p'], ent[ 'li'],ent['col'], ent[ 'sty'], ent['nu'],ent['ge'],ent[ 'rr'], ent['ssty']) for ent in ents]
ents_dt = dtype([('n', 'O'), ('p', 'O'), ('li', 'i1'), ('col', 'O'), ('sty', 'O'), ('nu', 'i1'), ('ge', 'i1'), ('rr', 'i1'), ('ssty', '<i4')])
entsRec = np.array(entsTuples,ents_dt)
```

and then i timeit.

---

Comment: Can you attach your data file and add a peace of code where you create the `dfEnts` and `ents` structures? `ents` look to me more like a list than a dict.

Comment: this just shows a small function call overhead; try this with 10000 elements

Comment: thx 4 your review .. sorry, yes, is a list of dics. anyway, dataFrame performance is my concern because i can understand this performance... what i doing wrong?? thnx

Comment: jeff, are you saying that pandas performs well only above a minimal amount of records/rows. is that a limitation documented somewhere? thnx

Comment: Viktor has a nice example; Sometimes with a tiny data set things will have different performances characteristics. Operations that take < 1ms are quite hard to optimize (and not worth the time to do so, unless they are called many many times). If that is the case then your should change how you are approaching the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list may have a small performance benefit when you work on small data sets, since the list comprehensions and dictionary lookups are very optimized in Python. But it's usually an insignificant difference. Once you try working with larger data sets you will notice a much bigger difference and start to feel the benefits that the pandas library provides.

```
ents = []
for i in xrange(0, 10000000):
    dic = {
        'n': i, 'p': i, 'li': i, 'col': i, 'sty': i,
        'nu': i, 'ge': i, 'rr': i, 'ssty': i
    } 
    ents.append(dic)
dfEnts = pd.DataFrame(ents)

%%timeit
a = dfEnts[(dfEnts["col"] == 44) & (dfEnts["sty"]== 44)]
10 loops, best of 3: 96.1 ms per loop

%%timeit
b = [ix for ix,ent in enumerate(ents) if (ent['col'] == 44) & (ent["sty"] == 44)]
1 loops, best of 3: 1.68 s per loop
```

Also pandas `DataFrame` provides much, much more functionality than a list of dicts, so I don't think they are even comparable.

Comment: thanks, so in the end we are saying that i shouldn't use pandas for smalls records of data .. numpy perform just fine ... and all the time i was thinking that pandas was an smart abstraction of np. im wrong, though.

Comment: pandas **is** a smart abstraction of NumPy. It uses NumPy arrays for under the hood. NumPy will behave the same way as pandas behaved for this example. In this example you used python lists not NumPy arrays.

Comment: Ah sorry, I missed that part. Structured/record array are a beast for itself :). They are a single continuous chunk of memory so NumPy is able to perform some optimizations that pandas cannot, since it's designed for a little bit different purpose.